# How to adb pull on galaxy s1 i9000 please?

Tags: partitions

How to adb pull on galaxy s1 i9000 please?

I need to install TWRP but no s1 i9000 (classic ) version was ever made due to lack of a certain recovery partition structure on s1 .
But it is available on S1 Blaze and S1 Fascination which were newer but lower in specs.

Clockworkmod for XXJJVQ Baseband version of i9000 is in many places as a notworking link on forums.

Anybody have Clockworkmod for s1 i9000 XXJJVQ please ?
Or a workaround to make partition image on s1 i9000 ?

I recorded a very important proof today and the file was not saved.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2015-10-09-cwm-6-0-5-1-philz-touch-6-59-0-libtouch_gui-1-42.2201860